# How can i access div text inside the label or in string?ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a `div` in which user insert `SQL` query and I want to access this query in `codebehind` and pass to `sqlcmd` and execute query and show result to user but I'm unable to do this. How can I do this?
Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="load" Text="Submit" />
        <asp:label ID="TextBox1" ForeColor="White" runat="server"></asp:label>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

my aspx.cs (codebehind) is :

```
public void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl footer = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("editor");
    String cmd = footer.InnerHtml.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text = cmd;
}
```

I'm getting this error:
[image: LINK]

Comment: Why use asp:Label instead asp:TextBox? asp:Label just shows text, not to insert them. Try changing to asp:TextBox and let me know the result.

Comment: I try this `<asp:TextBox   ID="TextBox1" ForeColor="White" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>` but same error occur as i mention above in `screenshot`

Comment: did you try putting a runat="server" in your div tag?

Comment: I try this if i put `runat="server" `then div not shown in output

Comment: try my answer, it will work for you..............

Answer (score 0):

Add runat="server" to your DIV tag and it should resolve your issue.

```
  <div id="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: I try this if i put `runat="server"` then div not shown in output

Answer (score 0):

Add `runat="server"` in div like this:-

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

and use this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("body");
        HtmlGenericControl footer = (HtmlGenericControl)mainContent.FindControl("editor");
        String cmd = footer.InnerHtml.ToString();
        TextBox1.Text = cmd;
    }
```

where `body` is  `ContentPlaceHolderID` you can find this on your content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: @Ashley you label `TextBox1` has `ForeColor` is white if your `background color` is `white` then you may not able to see the text make it `Black` if your `background color` is `white`

Comment: i already tell you 2 time and now I'm telling 3rd time that when i put `runat="server"` tag then my div not shown in output when i remove `runat="server"` then it shown

Comment: @Ashley it will show, try the code i have provided, also let me know if you are using ang jquery/javascript to put data in that div

Comment: here is my question.I asked now.Please answer it [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833324/how-can-i-get-text-from-inside-the-div-in-code-behind-asp-net-c/37833445#37833445)

Comment: use my code and instead of `$("#editor")` use `$("div[ID$='editor']")`