# How can i get text from inside the div in code behind asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

Actually I'm creating a SQL QUERY editor in which user enter query then i get this text and pass to SQL COMMAND and execute query and display result to the user in `GRIDVIEW`.But,problem is how can i get text in `codebehind` from `<div contenteditable="true" ></div>`.
I have 3 files which are `html`,`JScript.js`,`StyleSheet.css`.
I put `textbox` just for check to retrieve value in `textbox` on button click but its not working.
Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="load" Text="Submit" />
<asp:TextBox   ID="TextBox1" ForeColor="White" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is aspx.cs code:

```
public void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HtmlGenericControl footer = (HtmlGenericControl)mainContent.FindControl("editor");
String cmd = footer.InnerHtml.ToString();
TextBox1.Text = cmd;
}
```

here is JScript.js code:

```
$(function () {
$("#editor").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").trim();
        var word = text.split(" ");
        var newHTML = "";

        $.each(word, function (index, value) {
            switch (value.toUpperCase()) {
                case "SELECT":
                case "FROM":
                case "WHERE":
                case "LIKE":
                case "BETWEEN":
                case "NOT LIKE":
                case "FALSE":
                case "NULL":
                case "FROM":
                case "TRUE":
                case "NOT IN":
                    newHTML += "<span class='statement'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
                    break;
                default:
                    newHTML += "<span class='other'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
            }
        });

        $(this).html(newHTML);

        //// Set cursor postion to end of text
        var child = $(this).children();
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        $(this)[0].focus();
    }
});
});
```

All code working fine,but problem is how can i get text in `codebehind` from inside `div` which user enter in the form of query.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat=server` for your `DIV` to access in code-behind as

```
<div id="editor" runat=server contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: If i add `runat="server"` then div not shown in output.It display only without `runat="server"`

Comment: @Ashley What do you mean by "div not shown in output"

Answer (score 0):

Add `runat="server"` in div like this:-

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" runat="server">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Modify your script instead of `$("#editor")` use `$("div[ID$='editor']")` as below:

when you add `runat="server"` after render Id automatically changes so now your id is not any more `editor` because of `runat` tag it changed it will be like this `ctl00_body_editor`(may be different just for your understanding i am writing this) so this -> `$("div[ID$='editor']")` will give you exact id.

```
$(function () {
$("div[ID$='editor']").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").trim();
        var word = text.split(" ");
        var newHTML = "";

        $.each(word, function (index, value) {
            switch (value.toUpperCase()) {
                case "SELECT":
                case "FROM":
                case "WHERE":
                case "LIKE":
                case "BETWEEN":
                case "NOT LIKE":
                case "FALSE":
                case "NULL":
                case "FROM":
                case "TRUE":
                case "NOT IN":
                    newHTML += "<span class='statement'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
                    break;
                default:
                    newHTML += "<span class='other'>" + value + "&nbsp;</span>";
            }
        });

        $(this).html(newHTML);

        //// Set cursor postion to end of text
        var child = $(this).children();
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        $(this)[0].focus();
    }
});
});
```

and use this code

```
protected void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("body");
        HtmlGenericControl footer = (HtmlGenericControl)mainContent.FindControl("editor");
        String cmd = footer.InnerHtml.ToString();
        TextBox1.Text = cmd;
    }
```

where `body` is  `ContentPlaceHolderID` you can find this on your content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
```

Use this html for your content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="load" Text="Submit" />
<asp:TextBox   ID="TextBox1" ForeColor="Black" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: @Ashley try this answer and don't forget to modify your script -> replace `$("#editor")` with `$("div[ID$='editor']")`

Comment: @Asnari i follow all your instructions but sorry to say it's not working.When i use `runat="server"` then it's not expected div show .here is image [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/6VpdHbB.png) it's not good.But when i use without `runat="server"` then it's shown good but text not getting in code behind .Here is output with `runat="server"` [LINK](http://i.imgur.com/xdsKBlE.png)

Comment: @Ashley have you changed the script as I mentioned?

Comment: @Ashley when you add `runat="server"` after render I'd automatically changes so in your script change `$("#editor")` to `$("div[ID$='editor']")` then it will work for sure 100% let me know if you have any confusion??

Comment: yes i change I replace `$("#editor")` with `$("div[ID$='editor']")`  here is starting of `JScript.js`  `$(function () {
    $("div[ID$='editor']").on("keydown keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { `

Comment: and here is my `masterpage` `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="body" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`